# OpenMP threads appear to execute serially

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, openmp

I have an application which should essentially evaluate the reverse polish notation of a mathematical expression in parallel may times. My problem is i'm not seeing any gain in performance when using OpenMP. (Im using VS2008, the /openmp compiler option is set.)

My main loop looks like this:

```
int nMaxThreads = std::min(omp_get_max_threads(), s_MaxNumOpenMPThreads);
int nThreadID;
omp_set_num_threads(nMaxThreads);

#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static) private(nThreadID)
for (i=0; i<nBulkSize; ++i)
{
  nThreadID = omp_get_thread_num();
  printf("Thread %d Idx %d start",nThreadID, i);
  results[i] = EvalRPNInParallel(i, nThreadID);
  printf(" -- %d Idx %d end\n",nThreadID, i);
}
```

The printfs are there solely for debugging purposes to see if any parallel action is taking place (which should mix them up inbetween the 4 threads). From the debug output i can see that indeed multiple threads are beeing spawned. Each thread is getting a certain chunk of the loop but the threads do not appear to execute in parallel. Thread 0 is calculating its chunk of the loop, then thread 1 calculates its chunk and so on. No parallel execution whatsoever. The Execution time is exactly as if openmp was'nt even active. 
EvalRPNInParallel is a member function that does the RPN calculation. I do not use any locks, mutexes omp barriers inside this function.

```
double Foo::EvalRPNInParallel(int nOffset, int nThreadID) const
{
  double *Stack = &m_vStackBuffer[nThreadID * (m_vStackBuffer.size() / 4);
  for (const SToken *pTok = m_pRPN;  ; ++pTok)
  {
    switch (pTok->Cmd)
    {
      case  cmADD:  --sidx; Stack[sidx] += Stack[1+sidx]; continue;
      case  cmSUB:  --sidx; Stack[sidx] -= Stack[1+sidx]; continue;
      case  cmMUL:  --sidx; Stack[sidx] *= Stack[1+sidx]; continue;
      case  cmVAR:  Stack[++sidx] = *(pTok->Val.ptr + nOffset);  continue;
      // ...
      // ...
      // ...
      case  cmEND:  return Stack[m_nFinalResultIdx];  
    }
  }
}
```

The strange thing is, if i'm deliberately slowing down EvalRPNInParallel with an unnecessary for loop i'm indeed seeing parallel execution of EvalRPNInParallel as i would expect it. Does anyone have an idea why i'm not seeing any gain from using OpenMP her?

**[update]**
I also tried the following openMP constructs neither one did show any parallel exection:

```
int nIterationsPerThread = nBulkSize/nMaxThreads;
#pragma omp parallel for private(nThreadID, j, k) shared(nMaxThreads, nIterationsPerThread) ordered
for (i=0; i<nMaxThreads; ++i)
{
  for (j=0; j<nIterationsPerThread; ++j)
  {
    nThreadID = omp_get_thread_num();
    k = i*nIterationsPerThread + j;
    printf("Thread %d Idx %d start",nThreadID, k);
    results[k] = ParseCmdCodeBulk(k, nThreadID);
    printf(" -- %d Idx %d end\n",nThreadID, k);
  }
}
```

using sections:

```
#pragma omp parallel shared(nBulkSize) private(nThreadID, i)
{
  #pragma omp sections nowait
  {
    #pragma omp section
    for (i=0; i<(nBulkSize/2); ++i)
    {
      nThreadID = omp_get_thread_num();
      printf("Thread %d Idx %d start",nThreadID, i);
      results[i] = ParseCmdCodeBulk(i, nThreadID);
      printf(" -- %d Idx %d end\n",nThreadID, i);
    } // end of section

    #pragma omp section
    for (i=nBulkSize/2; i<nBulkSize; ++i)
    {
      nThreadID = omp_get_thread_num();
      printf("Thread %d Idx %d start",nThreadID, i);
      results[i] = ParseCmdCodeBulk(i, nThreadID);
      printf(" -- %d Idx %d end\n",nThreadID, i);
    } // end of section
  }
} // end of sections
```

Comment: creating/stating threads has some overhead - it's not trivial. if your `EvalRPN` function is fast enough, it could simply be over by the time the second thread has a chance to start.

Comment: msvc's printf contains a critical section.  If you use OutputDebugString or remove them does it change the behavior?

Comment: The loop is broken into 4 chunks each thread gets a number of loops turns not just a single one. The threads arn't created at every loop turn they execute a large part of the for loop each. I see thread 1 calculation 500 loops then i see thread 2 calculating a few hundrets loops than thread 3. I'll never see two threads working simulaneousely. The printf's may have a lock but this wouldnt prevent a thread switch between the two printfs. Setting the chunksize manually doesnt work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classic Heisenberg, observing a thread affects its behavior.  The printf() function is slow, surely much slower then your expression evaluator.  And has to acquire a lock to prevent the characters in the string from getting intermingled with console output requested by other threads.  The odds that more than one thread can make it to the EvalRPNInParallel function *concurrently* are just not very good.  Which you can't observe with your diagnostics btw.

And the usual advice applies, only optimize your code *after* you measured it three times to find out what the bottleneck might be.  I'd be surprised if it takes more than a couple of microseconds.  You cannot win in that case, starting the thread already takes longer.  The same measurement you make to find the bottleneck will also tell you if threading gets you ahead.

Comment: I rule that out the printfs were added after observing the nonexisting performance increase. The evaluation tself is taking only microseconds but the threads are not created at every loop turn but they get a chunk of calculations.

Comment: The printf aren't the problem here. If i remove it entirely and write debug information into an array instead i'm seeing the same result: Thread 1 calculates its chunk, then thread 2, then thread 3 and finally thread 4. But they do not work in parallel. Each thread calculates several thousand expressions. This takes more than a few milliseconds. Also even reorganizeing the loops into a double loop with a distinct outer loop for the number of cores the result does not change.

Comment: Your code snippet shows no evidence of this, I have nothing to look at to diagnose your problem.

Comment: And i really appreciate this, i updated the original question with more samples of what i already tried.

Comment: I'm also taking a look, but like @Hans I can't see any reason why they should execute in serial, unless `omp_get_num_threads() == 1` (I'm assuming it isn't that simple) given there are no locks etc elsewhere. +1 for the mention of optimisation and the cost of threading.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I made some more tests without the printfs and i'm pretty sure now that the threads do run in parallel (my first test without the printf's was simple incorrect, sorry my bad.) Although this doesnt solve my problem (there is no performance increase) it answers my question. So i'm accepting this answer. I will repost another question with a console example hoping someone might be able to tell me why i'm not seeing any speedup.